# Using go get to retrieve from a local repository and private repo

Tags: github, go

Hi my goal is to have `go get` retrieve from a private repo on github.

The problem I am having is that I am committing into a folder structure that is outside of my GOPATH. So I want to test that what I have works before I commit.

1) How do I make go get retrieve from a local directory that is outside my path. Say my go code is in a directory $HOME/project/ How can I tell go get to retrieve the package and place it in the appropriate github.com folder structure so that my package references work?

2) How can I use go get to pull from a private repo? Should it just ask for my username and password?

Comment: Why **must** you have source in a folder not under $GOPATH ? You are aware that you can have multiple paths as $GOPATH ?

Comment: you should have your project in golang source path, biggest mistake new golang devs make is putting stuff outside the golang path. GOLANG workspace is build to be managed by go dont try to change that as it will not work.

Answer (score 3):

1. This is not really possible without serious hacks. The "simplest" hack is probably using a symlink, bind mount, or NFS mount.

   That being said, it's best to just follow `GOPATH`. You don't have to like it, but for better or worse Go is opinionated about these sort of things, and your life will be easier.
2. Use ssh keys for authorisation (rather than a user/password) and add this to your `~/.gitconfig` to make sure `ssh` is used:

   ```
   [url "git@github.com:"]
       insteadOf = https://github.com/
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do neither 1) nor 2) (easily). `go get` is not intended to be used this way.